# The union of a finite number of bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^p$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Theorem:** The union of a finite number of bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^p$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^p$.

**Proof:**

Let $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_n$ be bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Let $M_1, M_2, \dots , M_n$ be real positive numbers such that $E_i \subseteq B(0,M_i)$.

Let $M = \max \{ M_1, M_2, \dots, M_n \}$

We then have that $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i \subseteq B(0,M)$

Can someone please show me how they got the inclusion above? I tried showing it, but I keep on getting stuck.

**Update:**

From the answers given, I did the following:

Let $x \in \displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i \implies x \in E_i$ for some $i=1,2,\dots, n$. Since we know $E_i$ is bounded, we know $x \in E_i \implies x \in B(0, M_i) \implies | x-0| = |x| < M_i \leq M \implies x \in B(0,M)$.

Notice, however, that we have shown that $x \in \displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i \implies  x \in B(0,M) \implies \displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i \subseteq B(0,M)$

Comment: Be careful with the part "since we know $E_i$ is bounded..." That's was stated initially and you've got $E_i\subseteq B(0,M_i)$ from there, you should better say "since $E_i\subseteq B(0,M_i)$..." Also, try avoid using $i$ as an index for the union and as a particular number (when you say "for some $i$..."), that's why I've used $j$ instead of $i$.

Comment: Everything else is fine. A suggestion for the last line is the following: "Notice we have shown that $x\in B(0,M)$, since $x\in \cup E_i$ is arbitrary, we have $\cup E_i \subseteq B(0,M)$".

Comment: @DanielEscudero - Thank you! :) :). I really appreciate it a lot. You've given me some excellent pointers with regards to improving my mathematics "writing skills" :). Your help has been far more than the scope of the question. :). You really went out of your way to help me grow here :) Thank you so much for that :)

Comment: You're welcome! :) (Take a look to Omnomnomnom's answer, it uses properties from sets: if $A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq C$, then $A\cup B\subseteq C$. That's a more elegant proof in my opinion, however, it does need those properties to be known)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the definition of inclusion, and the boudness of each $E_i$ that was stated initially. Your proof would look like this:

> Let $x\in\cup_{i=1}^n E_i$, then (by definition) $x\in E_j$ for some $j\in \{1,...,n\}$, since $E_j\subseteq B(0,M_j)$ and $M_j\leq M$...

Can you prove that $x\in B(0,M)$? (note this would finish the proof).

Comment: Thank you! Can you check my answer now in the update? :)

Comment: @Dillon Done!!.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that
$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^n B(0,M_i) \subseteq B(0,M)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider  generic point in one of the subsets. It will be contained in one of the $B(0,M_i)$. Then it will also be contained in any ball $B(0,M_k)$ , with $M_k > M_i$. Then use $M$ as you defined it. If $x$ is in $B(0,M_i)$, then it is also in $B(0,M)$.